# Why does this code trigger an infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am writing some simple code to parse a file and return the number of lines but the little red box in eclipse won't go off so I assume I am triggering an infinite loop. Th Text file i am reading has only 10 lines...here's the code: What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestParse {    
    private int noLines = 0;    
    public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException {
        Scanner defaultFR = new Scanner (new FileReader ("C:\\workspace\\Recommender\\src\\IMDBTop10.txt"));
        TestParse demo = new TestParse();
        demo.nLines (defaultFR);
        int x = demo.getNoLines ();
        System.out.println (x);
    }   
    public TestParse() throws IOException
    {
        noLines = 0;
    }
    public void nLines (Scanner s) {
        try {
            while (s.hasNextLine ())
                noLines++;
        }
        finally {
                if (s!=null) s.close ();
        }
    }
    public int getNoLines () {
        return noLines;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling `s.nextLine()` in the while-loop:

should be:

```
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
           s.nextLine(); // <<<
            noLines++;

          }
```

Comment: Great Thanks alot!...A little sleep deprived that was a rather dumb omission...Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You only check `hasNextLine` within your loop. This checks if another line is present but does not read it. Let it follow by `nextLine` and your code will work.

```
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    s.nextLine();
    noLines++;
}
```